# How to store data from a MariaDB in my node.js environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, mariadb, store

I have a MariaDB that stores Energy-Data like voltage, frequency and so on. My aim is to visualize the data in a Web-application. Though i achieved to connect the MariaDB to node.js and log the data on a specific port thanks to the code below, i don't have a clue how to store this data for further mathematic operations or visualizations.

How can i store the data for further operations?

```
const express = require('express');
const pool = require('./db');
const app = express();
const port = 4999;

// expose an endpoint "persons"
app.get('/persons', async (req, res) => {
    let conn;
    try {
        // make a connection to MariaDB
        conn = await pool.getConnection();

        // create a new query to fetch all records from the table
        var query = "select * from Herget_Netz2_WirkleistungL1";

        // run the query and set the result to a new variable
        var rows = await conn.query(query);

        console.log('Daten kommen');
        

        // return the results
        res.send(rows);
             
    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    } finally {
        if (conn) return conn.release();
    }
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on pfort ${port}`));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is quite broad.

It sounds like you need to set up a frontend and call fetch on your endpoint, something like:

```js
fetch(<your-url>/persons)
  .then(r => r.json())
  .then(yourData => "<p>" + yourData "</p>")
```

Your data will be interpolated into HTML then. You will need to iterate over it.

The "storage" will take place in the variable you define in the second `.then(yourData)` of the promise for you to do further operations on.

You should search for tutorials like "set up frontend with maria db database and node backend".